# DATASTAGE capabilities

Tags: datastage

I'm a Linux programmer.
I used to write code in order to get things done: java perl php c.
I need to start working with DATA STAGE.

All I see is that DATA STAGE is working on table/csv style data and doing it line by line.

I want to know if DATA STAGE can work on file that are not table/csv like. can it load 
data into data structures and run function on them, or is it limited to working 
only on one line at a time.

thank you for any information that you can give on the capabilities of DATA SATGE

Answer (score 0):

IBM (formerly Ascential) DataStage is an ETL platform that, indeed, works on data sets by applying various transformations.

This does not necessarily mean that you are constrained on applying only single line transformations (you can also aggregate, join, split etc). Also, DataStage has it's own programming language - BASIC - that allows you to modify the design of your jobs as needed.

Lastly, you are still free to call external scripts from within DataStage (either using the DSExecute function, Before Job property, After Job property or the [Command stage](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/iisinfsv/v8r5/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.swg.im.iis.ds.serverjob.dev.doc/topics/c_dsvjbref_Command_Stage.html)).

Please check the [IBM Information Center](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/iisinfsv/v8r5/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.swg.im.iis.ds.serverjob.dev.doc/topics/r_dsvjbref_BASIC_Programming.html) for a comprehensive documentation on BASIC Programming.

You could also check the [DSXchange](http://www.dsxchange.com/) forums for DataStage specific topics.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it can, as Razvan said you can join, aggregate, split. It can uses loops and external scripts, it can also handles XML.
My advice for you is that if you have large quantities of data you're gonna have to work on then datastage is your friend, else if the data that you're going to have to load is not very big then it's going to be easier to use JAVA, c, or any programming language that you know.

Answer (score 0):

You can all times of functions , conversions , manipulate the data. mainly Datastage is used for ease of use when you handling humongous data from datamart /datawarehouse.

The main process of datastage would be ETL - Extraction Transformation Loading.
If a programmer uses 100 lines of code to connect to some database here we can do it with one click. 
Anything can be done here even c , c++ coding in a rountine activity.

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about hierarchical files, like XML or JSON, the answer is yes.
If you are talking about complex files, such as are produced by COBOL, the answer is yes.
All using in-built functionality (e.g. Hierarchical Data stage, Complex Flat File stage).  Review the DataStage palette to find other examples.